# Convert number to date and datetime in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have these numbers:

-44384.520833333299 (to datetime). It should be 07/07/2021  12:30:00

-44384 (to date). It should be 07/07/2021

How can I convert these numbers and a list of them in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
openxlsx::convertToDateTime(44384.520833333299)
# [1] "2021-07-07 12:30:00 CEST"
openxlsx::convertToDate(44384)
# [1] "2021-07-07"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, using `lubridate`:

```r
library(lubridate)

# The first argument must be in seconds

as_datetime(3600*24*44384.520833333299, origin="1899-12-30")

#> [1] "2021-07-07 12:29:59 UTC"

as_date(44384, origin="1899-12-30")

#> [1] "2021-07-07"
```